# JQ:How to remove items from json array with conditions?

Tags: jq

I have the following few json array objects that Id like to filter using a single jq command.

```
{
    "Sid": "bla1",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": "*"
    },
    "Action": "blabla",
    "Resource": "blablablabla",
    "Condition": {
      "ArnLike": {
        "aws:bla": [
          "blablablablablabla*",
          "blablablablabla*",
          "blablablabla:*"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

How can i remove item "blablablablablabla:*" from "Condition->ArnLike->aws:bla" if "Sid" == "bla1"

expected result like below

```
{
    "Sid": "bla1",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": "*"
    },
    "Action": "blabla",
    "Resource": "blablablabla",
    "Condition": {
      "ArnLike": {
        "aws:bla": [
          "blablablablabla*",
          "blablablabla:*"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `select` the items that match the condition `.Sid == "bla1"`, then `del`ete from them any entry `.Condition.ArnLike."aws:bla"[]` that matches `. == "blablablablablabla*"`.

```sh
jq 'select(.Sid == "bla1") |=
  del(.Condition.ArnLike."aws:bla"[] | select(. == "blablablablablabla*"))
'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Mb7luae8vn)

If your objects are in an array, apply this using a `map` onto that array.

```sh
jq 'map(select(.Sid == "bla1") |=
  del(.Condition.ArnLike."aws:bla"[] | select(. == "blablablablablabla*"))
)'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/E5fQ3hkKm5)

Comment: I find it a bit odd that some of the query is outside the `del` and some of it inside. It could be placed entirely inside as follows: `del( select(.Sid == "bla1") | .Condition.ArnLike."aws:bla"[] | select(. == "blablablablablabla*") )`